# Obter primeiro valor antes da vírgula

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá estou tendo dificuldades em armazenar o valor do dia que precede a vírgula:

```
<span id="organizerContainer-date">Novembro 3, 2018</span>
```

Gostaria de armazenar esse valor pra fazer algumas coisas. Se alguém já fez isso antes poderia me informar como seria fazer isso usando o jquery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando jQuery:

```js
dia_ = $('#organizerContainer-date').text().split(' ')[1].replace(/\D/g, '');
console.log(dia_); // retorna 3
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="organizerContainer-date">Novembro 3, 2018</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Não precisas de jQuery para isso, com JavaScript é simples e podes fazer assim, partindo do principio que o formato da data é sempre o mesmo:

```js
var span = document.getElementById("organizerContainer-date");
var nr = span.innerHTML.split(/[\s,]/).filter(Boolean)[1];
console.log(nr); // 3
```

```html
<span id="organizerContainer-date">Novembro 3, 2018</span>
```

Comment: Olá Sergio, podes explicar a lógica por detrás do `filter(Boolean)` e porque não diretamente `split(...)[1]` ?

Comment: @Isac para o exemplo da pergunta não é necessário, mas a minha experiência é que há sempre variações na string de input. Se por exemplo houver um espaço antes do nome do mês, então o código ia falhar. Ou um espaço a mais entre as palavras/numero, então ia falhar também. Assim como a resposta aceite também falharia. Por isso uso `.filter(Boolean)` que basicamente remove posições vazias na array que o `split` cria. Ficou claro? talvez seja interessante juntar isto à resposta?

Comment: Sim eu já tinha percebido que estavas a remover as vazias só não estava a ver porque. Acho que de facto torna a solução melhor e mais robusta. Obrigado pela resposta